# Restart an enterprise application using command line in WLS 10.3.3

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic

I typically start up my development version of WLS 10.3.3 from the command line by launching startWebLogic.cmd in my domain folder.

Then, as developers typically do, I make changes to the source of my Java EE app and rebuild it using ant.  Then, I go to the WLS Administration Console -> mydomain -> deployments and select my Java EE app and click the Update button to "refresh" the application.  I've set it up such that the path of the application points against my Java EE app's project directory, which has META-INF, src and web underneath it.  My classes are deployed underneath web/WEB-INF/classes.

I'd like to be able to use dos to "refresh" the application after I rebuild it.  I figure I don't have to open up the WLS Admin Console everytime I just want to refresh this application.

Could someone please explain how I can use dos to "refresh" (stop, start, or whatever will update it on WLS) the application on WLS?

(as a side note - my WLS server is currently configured to only accept "HTTPS" protocol communication)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, I needed to do the following in order to use WebLogic Scripting Tool (WLST).
  I'm running a development 10.1.3.3 server on my PC which has an OS of Windows XP Professional.
I am only using SSL ("HTTPS") as well on WLS (found under your server general configuration page, specifically "SSL Listen Port Enabled").
Make sure to enable tunneling on the server by going to your server -> protocols -> general and clicking on Enable Tunneling.
Set your WLS environment variables by running
 `"your_wls_domain_install_dir"\wlserver\server\bin\setWLSEnv.cmd.`
Launch the WSLT tool by then running
`java -Dweblogic.security.SSL.ignoreHostnameVerification=true -Dweblogic.security.TrustKeyStore=DemoTrust weblogic.WLST`
(As can be seen in the above command, I'm specifically using the DemoTrust key store which is the default one configured with a WLS install)
Then, you can connect into your server...
`connect ('user','pwd','https://127.0.0.1:4443')`
From there, I used the redeploy command that Billy Bob mentioned.
The link that he provided is a good quick reference for all the WLST commands.

Answer (score 3):

Use WLST. On linux you would use wlst.sh. On windows I believe it is wlst.cmd.

```
SOME_PATH/wlserver_10.3/common/bin/wlst.sh
```

Then connect to WLS instance using credentials & proper host and port.

```
connect('user','pass','t3://localhost:7001')
```

Now just tell it to redeploy.

```
redeploy('your_app_name')
```

It really is that simple.

You can also deploy from WLST in the same manner.

```
deploy('your_app_name','path_to_your_app/yourapp.ear','ServerName')
```

Undeploy is done just like redeploy.

```
undeploy('your_app_name')
```

This quick reference has all the WLST commands.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13813/quick_ref.htm#WLSTC113

Comment: This post was very helpful - thank you - i'm going to provide more detail into how I was able to get this working so that it will hopefully help the next developer who's trying to play the role of "app server admin"...

Comment: Here's some scratch notes that I don't want to lose that I will include in the answer later...

Comment: Make sure to enable tunneling on the server by going to your server -> protocols -> general and clicking on Enable Tunneling.  Set your WLS environment variables by running "your_domain_install_dir"\wlserver\server\bin\setWLSEnv.cmd.  Launch the WSLT tool by then running "java -Dweblogic.security.SSL.ignoreHostnameVerification=true -Dweblogic.security.TrustKeyStore=DemoTrust weblogic.WLST"  Then, you can connect into your server using HTTPS (forgot to mention that I was using this protocol in particular...)  connect ('user','pwd','https://127.0.0.1:4443')